# Passing data (other than payload) via websockets

Tags: java, spring, session, websocket, spring-websocket

Once the websocket session has been established, is it possible to pass data other than using session.getAsyncRemote().sendText(**)) across the session?

I am using 
 javax.websocket.* as ClientEndpoint
 and spring-websocket for server.

I have tried using:

```
session.getRequestParameterMap().putAll(bMap); //This gives me exception 
session.getPathParameters().putAll(aMap); //This gives me exception
session.getUserProperties().put("dataE", "dataF");; //This goes through fine
```

And I am not able to see the data on server side:

```
Map<String, Object> aMap = stStandard.getNativeSession().getUserProperties();
```

This map comes as blank on server side.Please let me know if more information is needed. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;

@ClientEndpoint
public class TestSpring {
            @OnMessage
            public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException,
                    InterruptedException {
                Map aMap = new HashMap();
                aMap.put("dataA", "dataB");
                try {
                    session.getPathParameters().putAll(aMap);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }           
                Map bMap = new HashMap();

                List<String> bList = new ArrayList<String>();

                bList.add("dataC");
                try {
                    bMap.put("dataD", bList);
                    session.getRequestParameterMap().putAll(bMap);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    session.getUserProperties().put("dataE", "dataF");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }            
                session.getAsyncRemote().sendText("Data to be sent");
            }

            @OnOpen
            public void onOpen() {
                System.out.println("Client connected");
            }            
            @OnClose
            public void onClose() {
                System.out.println("Connection closed");
            }

        }




import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.web.socket.BinaryMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketExtension;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.AbstractWebSocketHandler;

import com.sap.websocket.inMemoryWebSockets.KeepInMemoryWebSockets;

public class WebsocketEndPoint extends AbstractWebSocketHandler {   

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session,
            TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        session.getHandshakeHeaders();
        StandardWebSocketSession stStandard = (StandardWebSocketSession) session;
        try {
            Map<String, Object> aMap = stStandard.getNativeSession()
                    .getUserProperties();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        TextMessage binaryMessage = new TextMessage(new String(
                "Hello Client. This is message sent from server"));
        session.sendMessage(binaryMessage);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleBinaryMessage(WebSocketSession session,
            BinaryMessage message) throws Exception {           
    }    
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. Please review [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Session.html). To send data to the remote peer, you need to get the remote peer using one of the methods supplied. `getBasicRemote` would also work. The `session` is on _your side_, changing it doesn't send data across. By definition, the payload _is_ the data you are sending.

Comment: I am trying to pass the custom data (across the session) after the websocket session has been established between client and server. Is there any way to do that? other than session.getBasicRemote().send* or session.getAsyncRemote().send*.

Comment: No. You do not pass data "across the session". The session is a local construct. The payload is, by definition, the data you send.

Comment: Is there any other way??

Comment: This is a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it you are _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: So basically i want to create/maintain a pool of websockets between client and server. So the requirement is that some client specific data needs to be passed from the client to the server across these websockets. but i want to delink the socket from the client data.

Comment: Why would you need a "pool" of websockets on the client? This all seems very odd.

Comment: So my scenario is : Client -->Server A -->Server B So the web sockets are established between a) client and server A b) Server A and Server  B The pool of web sockets needs to maintained for (b) and hence the question. Client send some data to server A and server A picks a session from pool and sends data to server B  (I want to avoid http overhead everytime this request comes up and hence the pool).

Comment: I still don't see why you need to exchange session data. Just keep a pool of websockets, if one dies then open another...